# undefined method `match' for nil:NilClass on save for object with carrierwave attachment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, carrierwave

A controller appears to be moving along smoothly:

```
 Pict Create (0.8ms)  INSERT INTO "picts" ("usercontent_id", "image", "caption", "user_id", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6) RETURNING "id"  [["usercontent_id", 94], ["image", "croc1.jpg"], ["caption", "emotional rescue"], ["user_id", 11], ["created_at", "2019-05-13 20:11:03.353852"], ["updated_at", "2019-05-13 20:11:03.353852"]]
  ↳ app/controllers/picts_controller.rb:36
   (0.6ms)  ROLLBACK
```

but rolls back on the `save` command (3rd line below)

```
@pict = Pict.new(pict_params)
authorize @pict
@pict.save
```

I removed all the validations (although in rails 5.2 the belongs_to is enforced - still I also tested by setting `optional: true` ), including a file-size validator...  and the result is always the same.

Frankly, I cannot even imagine what the nil applies to aside from `@pict` and yet it has proper parameters for all its attributes and passes Pundit policy for access control.

Thus I am assuming there is somethign wrong with the carrierwave engine. `carrierwave-aws` is also installed and the same

```
CarrierWave.configure do |config|
```

settings are used as an existing functioning application.  The model declares

```
mount_uploader :image, ImageUploader
```

who in turn:

```
class ImageUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
  include CarrierWave::MiniMagick
  storage :aws
```

parameters do show an image file being placed in a temporary bin.

```
{"utf8"=>"✓",
 "authenticity_token"=>"/ZY1FmOBBlVUdfayK3w7ws+4JgrbLt7U9gjvdyniOIqPMfvB10TUYEgvlDyyTTN9SCOu2zbYdb39Ydd37XdXvg==",
 "pict"=>
  {"nazione_id"=>"15",
   "image"=>
    #<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x00007f72d76516b0
     @content_type="image/jpeg",
     @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"pict[image]\"; filename=\"croc1.jpg\"\r\n" + "Content-Type: image/jpeg\r\n",
     @original_filename="croc1.jpg",
     @tempfile=#<File:/tmp/RackMultipart20190513-9509-f934ua.jpg>>,
   "caption"=>"emotional rescue",
   "regione_id"=>""},
 "usercontent_point"=>"Mitchell street darwin",
 "commit"=>" Add ",
 "locale"=>"en"}
```

What is causing the `undefined method 'match' for nil:NilClass` error?

**update**

```
aws-partitions (1.151.0) lib/aws-partitions/endpoint_provider.rb:82:in `block in partition_matching_region'
aws-partitions (1.151.0) lib/aws-partitions/endpoint_provider.rb:81:in `each'
aws-partitions (1.151.0) lib/aws-partitions/endpoint_provider.rb:81:in `find'
aws-partitions (1.151.0) lib/aws-partitions/endpoint_provider.rb:81:in `partition_matching_region'
aws-partitions (1.151.0) lib/aws-partitions/endpoint_provider.rb:70:in `get_partition'
aws-partitions (1.151.0) lib/aws-partitions/endpoint_provider.rb:23:in `signing_region'
aws-partitions (1.151.0) lib/aws-partitions/endpoint_provider.rb:99:in `signing_region'
aws-sdk-s3 (1.36.1) lib/aws-sdk-s3/plugins/s3_signer.rb:20:in `block in <class:S3Signer>'
aws-sdk-core (3.48.4) lib/seahorse/client/configuration.rb:70:in `call'
aws-sdk-core (3.48.4) lib/seahorse/client/configuration.rb:213:in `block in resolve_defaults'
aws-sdk-core (3.48.4) lib/seahorse/client/configuration.rb:57:in `each'
aws-sdk-core (3.48.4) lib/seahorse/client/configuration.rb:57:in `each'
aws-sdk-core (3.48.4) lib/seahorse/client/configuration.rb:212:in `resolve_defaults'
aws-sdk-core (3.48.4) lib/seahorse/client/configuration.rb:205:in `value_at'
aws-sdk-core (3.48.4) lib/seahorse/client/configuration.rb:189:in `block in resolve'
```

Comment: you can debug it by `@pict.errors` after callback happens.

Comment: Can you show code for `pict_params` ?

Comment: Can you post the stack trace? It will show you where `match` is being called

Comment: there is definitely carrierwave-aws looking to match regions.  I am assuming this refers to the AWS region...

Comment: I have a feeling you did not configure `AWS` correctly [Try looking at this](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-ruby#configuration-options). That error is trying to handle matching against a region string which falls back to a default region which is read from the config and it appears to be `nil` in the config which means you likely did not set one

Comment: Try using `@pict.save!`. This will throw an error that may give you more information.

Comment: [total embarrassment]  carrierwave-aws was effectively looking to match regions, but not finding the data to do so.  While the file was uploaded to the shared directory, the deploy did not have a symlink to that file.  @hashrocket : that suggestion unforntunately did not generate any additional info...  which was coherent with the state of affairs: nil

Answer (score 0):

`undefined method 'match' for nil:NilClass`  means the method is trying to run on something empty.

As one comment suggested, it could be a bad configuration.

Another hypothesis is that there is nothing to match against.  The whole configuration block is missing.  That file may be in the wrong directory or inexistent.

This particular case had a bad `deploy.rb` configuration to a development server without the symlink to the material file